# Expanding a number string formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel formula that searches a string of 4 numbers, in a single cell comma separated, then divides them by 2 (rounding down).

e.g. cell `A1` = `5,35,44,7`
Formula in cell `B1` = `2,17,22,3`

I would like to extended the formula to accommodate a string of numbers anywhere from 1 through 15.  The current formula that works perfect for a string of 1 to 4 numbers is below.  I'm wanting to keep the formula to a single cell without using VBA.  Thoughts on how to expand what I currently have?

```
=LEFT(IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,1,IFERROR(SEARCH(",",A2,1)-1,LEN(A2)))/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1,IFERROR(SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)-SEARCH(",",A2,1)-1,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(",",A2,1)))/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1,IFERROR(SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1)-SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)-1,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1))))/2,0),"")&","&IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(MID(A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1)+1,IFERROR(SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1)+1)-SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1)-1,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2,1)+1)+1)))/2,0),""),LEN(A2))
```

Comment: Hahah, I think if you try to expand up to 15, you cannot handle formula any more, I mean you get confused after 5 or 6 string numbers.

Comment: Are you saying Excel will not handle that large of a formula?  If so i'll need to evaluate a string of 10 at a minimum.  Is it something you can help with?

Comment: No, you can confused and it would be easily broken. I updated formula above to handle 1 to 4 string numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach can handle nearly an unlimited number of items in a single cell, but it requires more than one formula.

Place the value in **A1**.  In **A2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(--ROUNDDOWN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A$1,",",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))/2,0),"")
```

and copy down.  *(these are the parsed individual values, divided by two, and then rounded down)*

In **B2** enter:  `=A2`.  In **B3** enter:

```
=B2 & IF(A3="","","," & A3)
```

and copy down. *(this performs the re-concatenation)*.  Finally in **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("",A:A,0))
```

[image]

It is MUCH easier to use *VBA* to solve this problem.  This small *UDF()* does the same thing:

```
Public Function Brad(inpt As String) As String
    Dim a
    ary = Split(inpt, ",")
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For Each a In ary
            Brad = Brad & "," & .RoundDown(CDbl(a) / 2, 0)
        Next a
        Brad = Mid(Brad, 2)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: +1 for the UDF. I feel that while Excel formulas are fun - where they are cumbersome and problematic, VBA should be used to solve those issues...

Comment: This worked perfect. If you'd like toss the VBA answer as well and I can give you credit for it too.  Thank you.